# LINQ Dynamically Where

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have LINQ statement like this :

```
for (int i = 1; i < a + 1; i++)
{
    sumBubblee = dtErrCode.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => (r.Field<string>("ErrCode") == "000000FB") || (r.Field<string>("ErrCode") == "000000FF") || (r.Field<string>("ErrCode") == "000004FB") || (r.Field<string>("ErrCode") == "000004FF") || (r.Field<string>("ErrCode") == "000006FF"))
        .Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>(i)));
    rowBubble[i] = sumBubblee;
}
```

From the LINQ statement above, we know that I created 5 where condition statically.
What I am looking for: Is it possible to have a dynamically where clause?
I plan to insert all the where clause list in notepad file and then the LINQ read those `Where ("ErrCode")` from list in the notepad. And also it is easy if we want to add new where condition in notepad.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How about store these error code's value in an array? And in your `.Where()` to check whether the array `contains` the `ErrCode`. Is this the requirement you try to achieve?

Comment: yes,  those error code value in an array, and then check whether the array contains the ErrCode. After that i am getting those array value from notepad. Is it possible to read array in Where clause LinQ?

Comment: Hi @Randy, maybe you can attach the sample text file that you mentioned adding the where condition in the file in your question.

Comment: You could parse the text file and use it to  dynamically generate a list of function but I really think in code configuration would be a better way to go as Yong suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with the approach of pulling those names from a text file, then you could add them to a text file...

[image]

...and read the file and check for your error codes like this (I used spaces, but you could use commas or any other delimiter you want to - just be sure to set the delimiter in `.Split()` in the code below):

```
// read the error codes from your text file
var fileErrorCodes = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\path\to\your\file\errorCodes.txt");

// convert them to a string array (this is where you would use 
// e.g. .Split(',') if you choose to separate your error codes with a comma instead of a space
string[] errorCodes = fileErrorCodes.Split(' ');

// Now check if your errorCodes array contains any of the "ErrorCode" values in your dataset.
var result = dataset.AsEnumerable().Where(x => listOfErrorCodes.Contains(x.Field<string>("ErrorCode")));
```

Comment: So that's *O(n^2)*?

Comment: I don't know if that is a question or a rhetorical question?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file and add it to a list. Imagine 'myCustomErrorList' on example.

Your 'where' clause would look like this:

> `.Where(r => myCustomErrorList.Any(ce => ce == r.Field<string>("ErrCode")))`

Comment: I'd probably read the file into a `HashSet` rather than a `List`, then use `Contains()` in order to avoid scanning the whole list every time. But using a list is fine when we're only dealing with around 5 values.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following

```
var sumBubblee = dtErrCode.AsEnumerable()
     .Where(r => whatImLookingFor.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("ErrCode"), 16)))
     .Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>(i)));
```

And the test:

```
class R
{
    public string Error { get; set; }

    public int[] Fields {get; set;}

    public string Field<T>(string s) => Error;
    public string Field<T>(int i) => Fields[i].ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var dtErrCode = new List<R>() { 
        new R { Error = "000000FB", Fields = new int[]{0,444, 0} },
        new R { Error = "000000FF", Fields = new int[]{0,222, 0} },
        new R { Error = "000004FF", Fields = new int[]{0,0, 111} },
        };

    var whatImLookingFor = new [] { 0xFB, 0xFF, 0x4FB, 0x4FF, 0x6FF};

    var rowBubble = new int[3];

    var a = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < a + 1; i++) // I'm not sure why you're starting from 1 and not from 0
    {
        var sumBubblee = dtErrCode.AsEnumerable()
                    // .Select(r => new { ErrCode = r.Field<string>("ErrCode") }, I =  )
                    // .Select(s => )
                    .Where(r => whatImLookingFor.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("ErrCode"), 16)))
                    .Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>(i)));
        rowBubble[i] = sumBubblee;
    }

    //rowBubble [0,666,111]
}
```